# HC-05 Configuring. IOT project

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

First, I'm new to Arduino and Android programming. I had a college project, an automatic crash detection and notification. I used [this link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Realtime-MPU-6050A0-Data-Logging-With-Arduino-and-/?ALLSTEPS).

I have made all the connections correctly. The first problem I faced was that I couldn't connect my phone to the HC-05. It wasn't even discoverable and the LED didn't work. I thought my HC-05 was faulty and bought a new one. This one flashed the LED when connected. Then without going into AT command mode to change the baud rate I directly paired the HC-05 with my Android phone and tried the app.

The data from my Arduino wasn't being sent to the phone. I tried getting my HC-05 into AT command mode later on, but it wouldn't go into that mode. I tried all the tips [from here](http://www.instructables.com/id/AT-command-mode-of-HC-05-Bluetooth-module/). Still it wouldn't go into AT command mode. Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

Need to do initialization
- the BT pins:
 5v to 5v  arduino
 GND to GND arduino
 TX to RX arduino
 RX to TX arduino 
 solder pin 34 of BT  with wire and connected to any digital pin of arduino
 then, in void setup  set digital pin to low, and after delay, 1 sec, set pin to high
this way will let you get in AT command.